# How to send custom channel data when using web chat client with bot framework?

Tags: javascript, botframework

I'm trying to pass custom data along with every message that gets sent to my bot. There seems to be a way to achieve this but the example code is incomplete and because I'm a n00b at Javascript I have no clue how to get this right :-)

Here's the script I am using to set everything up:

```
const botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({
  secret: '@directLineSecret',
});

BotChat.App({
  bot: bot,
  botConnection: botConnection,
  user: user,
  resize: 'detect'
}, document.getElementById('bot'));
```

I am trying to apply what is shown here:

```
var dl = new BotChat.DirectLine({secret});

BotChat.App({botConnection: {
    … dl,
    postActivity: activity => dl.postActivity({
        … activity,
        channelData: // your data goes here 
    }),
        // other Chat props
});
```

The code above seems to intercept all calls to `postActivity` and adds custom channel data. But it also contains these unfortunate "...". How would I have to change my initialisation code so that it will intercept calls and add some keys/values to the `channelData` object?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer via the Github page of the web chat client. 
The "..." is not omitting any code but is [Javascript spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Spread_in_object_literals)

The correct code:

```
BotChat.App({
  botConnection:
  {
    ...botConnection,
    postActivity: activity => {
      // Add whatever needs to be added.                  
      activity.channelData.MyKey = "MyValue";
      return botConnection.postActivity(activity)
    }
  },
  bot: bot,
  user: user,
  resize: 'detect',
}, document.getElementById('bot'));
```